# How to redirect all pages to index page except the one page using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Currently, My site is redirecting all the pages to the Index.php page that have .php extension
But I don't want this on register.php page, Please help me out. Below is what I am doing.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*register.php) register.php [L,NC]

## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.\(.\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).script.(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

Try modifying this rule: `RewriteRule (.*register.php) register.php [L,NC]` to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} register\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of the request you want to exclude from the rule? I modified my answer some seconds ago so the directory to exclude can be at any level. Maybe you haven't tried the current version.

Comment: www.abc.com/fisrt.html
www.abc.com/fisrt.htm
www.abc.com/fisrt.php
www.abc.com/second.php
www.abc.com/register.php

will be redirected to www.abc.com/index.php

But I don't want www.abc.com/register.php to be redirected to 
www.abc.com/index.php

also when I run the page www.abc.com/register.php
I found in URL bar address is www.abc.com/register.php but the content is of index.php page.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. But @faa its not working :(

Comment: Please make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test. Don't understand why it doesn't work, but modified my answer again to include another NOT condition to make sure in no case the rule is applied to a request that holds the string `register.php`.

Comment: Yeah I cleared my browser's cache but no luck. Here is my site https://shipsus.com/register.php. The content is of Index.php page.

Comment: It goes to one `https` URL. The last rule seems to be mapping it again to `index.php`. I modified the answer, maybe you want to give it another try.

Comment: When the request is to `/register/register.php` there are membership and customer information forms displayed, is that the register page? If so, try moving `register.php` to root.

Comment: register.php is already on root but the issue is that when we run the register.php it shows the index page content but in url it shows domain/register.php.. i can't understand what's going wrong with it